# Xcode cannot click next while creating bots?

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-bots

I am trying to setup a bot for a test project. 
I have a mac mini that runs the Server app. The server is visible to the local network and all.
I go in Xcode after having shared the scheme and create a bot.

The problem is, I can't get the "NEXT" button at the bottom right to be enabled. So, I cannot continue with the creation of the bot.

The server is found and selected.

Why is the NEXT button disabled?

[image]

I also then tried commit the shared scheme  but I still don't have the option to click NEXT.
[image]

Comment: make sure your server is reachable. If your server is in private network you might want to get access to VPN

Answer (score 4):

This happens to me when I lose connection to my server, or Xcode loses connection.  Sometimes I need to remove the server from Xcode and re-add it.

[image: Preferences > Accounts > Add Server]