# After upgrading to Xcode 6.3, on launch I now get the error: "The Bonjour service could not be resolved."

Tags: ios, xcode, bonjour

After upgrading to Xcode 6.3, I now get an alert panel with the error: `The Bonjour service could not be resolved. The server may be temporarily unavailable. Contact your system administrator.` How can I fix this?

Comment: This duplicate was put on hold due to being off-topic.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644543/the-bonjour-service-could-not-be-resolved

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**. This question directly involves Xcode which is primarily used for programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was asked and voted off-topic on a duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644543/the-bonjour-service-could-not-be-resolved

Comment: Neither mine (closed) or this one is an off-topic, what's wrong with you @DCGoD ? This is a problem many Xcode 6.3 user experience...

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. I agree with the OP. I'll vote to reopen the other linked question(s) too. (though I would then vote to close one of the questions as a duplicate, probably the other since this has an answer)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Either delete or move out the file `~/Library/Application Support/Xcode/XCSServiceManager_KnownServices.plist`.

Comment: I have 0 files inside ~/Library/Application Support/Xcode/ still getting "The Bonjour service could not be resolved" error in Xcode 9. Can you please help here for further troubleshooting?

Comment: this answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788591/xcode-cannot-click-next-while-creating-bots